# inline_keyboard php Telegram

Tags: php, telegram

I am developing a Telegram bot in php and I have a problem with the CallbackQuery of the inline buttons.

This is the code I use to send the message that the inline button sends. this works fine

```
$keyboard_la_quiero = json_encode([
            "inline_keyboard" => [
                [
                    [
                        "text" => "\xF0\x9F\x9A\x95 La Quiero",
                        "callback_data" => "yo|1"
                    ]
                ]    
            ]
        ]);

        $data = http_build_query([
            'text' => "Informacion de la carrera",
            'chat_id' => $this->chat_id,
            'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            'reply_markup' => $keyboard_la_quiero
        ]);

        $r = Http::get($this->urlBot."/sendMessage", $data);
```

This is the code that is executed when receiving information. It also works correctly. But it doesn't get anything from callback_query or anything else on a button press.

```
if (isset($updates['callback_query'])) {
        $telegram->callback();
    }else{
        $telegram->start();
    }
```

Can someone help me figure out why? Greetings and thanks in advance

What I want is to be able to capture the response of a button and be able to send messages depending on the selection.